# Align text using tab

Tags: align, alignment, tabto

[image: text sample]

I can't get the text to align for REQ1.2, I'm trying to start at 3cm from the left. I'm using the following command:

```
    \newcommand{\newRequirement}[3]{
    % Params: Number, MoSCoW, Description
    \noindent\textbf{REQ#1[#2]}\tabto{3cm} #3\\
    \label{req:REQ#1} 
    }
```

How I've used the command:

```
\newRequirement{1.1}{MH}{que corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi 
sint occaecati cupiditate}
\newRequirement{1.2}{CH}{eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis   
praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint 
occaecati cupiditate} 
\newRequirement{1.3}{MH}{amus et iusto odio dignissimos du}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```tex
\noindent\textbf{REQ#1[#2]}\tabto{3cm} #3\\
```

with

```tex
{\parindent3cm \hangindent\parindent\noindent\hbox to\parindent{\textbf{REQ#1[#2]}\hfil}#3\par}
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed, thanks! [Paragraph Formatting](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Paragraph_formatting) I also found this useful guide for formatting!